# Issue with Razor HTML page declaring @model - <<namespace>> is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: asp.net, razor

In my HTML page I am seeing an issue with here I declare my model. Says the name `App.Web.ViewModel.DisputeModel` is a type which is not valid in the given context. I'm a little new to .NET so I'm unsure of what the issue is.

My HTML page:

```
@model App.Web.ViewModel.DisputeModel; //here is where I'm getting the error message

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="response-alert"></div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Dispute", "Dispute", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                UpdateTargetId = "response-alert",
            }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div id="dispute-form-section">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="num">Last Four Digits</label>
                                <span class="form-control">XXXX XXXX XXXX @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastFourDigits)</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="regarding">Description</label>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="dispute-submit-button">Submit</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Model:

```
namespace App.Web.ViewModel
{
    public class DisputeModel
    { 

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastFourDigits { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my Controller:

```
namespace App.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DisputeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Client _client;

        public DisputeController()
        {
            _client = new Client(Clients.ServiceClient);
        }

        public ActionResult Dispute()
        {
            DisputeModel dispute = new DisputeModel();

            return View("Dispute", dispute);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Dispute(DisputeModel dispute)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View("Dispute", dispute);

            var response = await _client.PostAsync($"/dispute", dispute);
            // code to handle response

            return View("Dispute", dispute);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I needed to remove the semicolons when I declare my model in my html page.